# dp/hdmi not working

Tags: hdmi

I have a laptop with built in dp port. I use dp to hdmi converter which is working fine on windows, but it is not working on elementary os loki.
[image]

Comment: This might be driver related, I don't have an answer but my USB C port enables HDMI adapter and shows up as a DP device. Not sure if it was ever solved for you. Did you have any success?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using the Intel Corporations display driver.
Do you have a built in graphics chip from either Nvidia or Amd
cause if you do you might want to install the latest drivers for ubuntu
from either of them to make it work properly.

I am not sure about AMD but to install nvidia drivers here is what you do

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers which is add the graphics repository for ubuntu based systems to your repository database

sudo apt-get update to activate the possibility of using it

after that install the latest driver by using sudo apt-get install nvidia-387